# Getting value out from square brackets in "aws ec2 describe-instances" output

Tags: bash

I am saving output of my command in a variable and using it in other command

```
instance_id=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] --filters "Name=tag:staging,Values=staging")
```

I get this output [ [ [ "i-09140824c1b7f9ea7" ] ] ]

How to I remove brackets from the output and use it in the variable in this command

```
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $instance_id --allocation-id allocid
```

I am new to bash so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your output is JSON. Use a JSON parser like `jq`.

Comment: By the way -- it's going to avoid some bugs (which would come up if your script was run with `globstar` or `nullglob` shell options enabled) if you put the query in single-quotes.

Comment: you could use `--output text` no?

Comment: Ahh -- telling `aws` to emit plaintext output would be even better.

Comment: @daveMiller, ...btw, note that you should *also* put quotes around `"$instance_id"` in your final command. Basically, *every* expansion should be quoted unless you have a very explicit reason not to; see https://shellcheck.net/ warning [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, ...I don't know AWS tooling well enough to stand by such an answer and support it if I added it myself -- maybe you could add an explicit answer to that effect? It's definitely good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the value *and* decode it from JSON to plain text with the following:

```
instance_id_json='[ [ [ "i-09140824c1b7f9ea7" ] ] ]'
instance_id=$(jq -r '.[][][]' <<<"$instance_id_json")
```

Consider changing your original code to:

```
instance_id_json=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters 'Name=tag:staging,Values=staging')
```

...note that we're putting the query in quotes (since it has glob characters), not just the filter (and since the filter is intended to be literal text with no expansions, we're defaulting to single-quotes rather than double as a matter of form).